# Using CasperJS within a regular JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs, spookyjs

I am trying to create a NodeJS program that utilizes CasperJS within it. I have run into the error that the module 'casper' cannot be found. As a result, I have tried to npm install spooky --save as I have read around that it is a driver, but I am still getting the same error as I was getting before.

Also, before trying to install SpookyJS, I tried

```
 var phantom = require('phantom');

 phantom.casperPath = '/path/to/casperjs';
 phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '/bin/bootstrap.js');
```

Which then gave me the error that injectJs is not a function. Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to contextualize a bit, here is an important reminder for everyone:

> While CasperJS is installable via npm, [it is not a NodeJS module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-node) and will not work with NodeJS out of the box. **You cannot load casper by using require(‘casperjs’) in node.** Note that CasperJS is not capable of using a vast majority of NodeJS modules out there. **Experiment and use your best judgement.**

This is where [**SpookyJS**](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS) comes into play... But how to make it work? (I assume you are on Linux.)

### 1. Make sure you have the right environment

- **Node.js** >= 0.8
- **PhantomJS** >= 1.9
- **CasperJS** >= 1.0

**Note:** SpookyJS works on my computer (Arch Linux) and I have the following setup:

`node --version` ---> **v7.7.4**
`npm --version` ---> **4.4.4**
`phantomjs --version` ---> **2.1.1**
`casperjs --version` ---> **1.1.3**

**PhantomJS** and **CasperJS** are installed globally.

### 2. Install SpookyJS locally (and its dependency: `tiny-jsonrpc`)

Create an empty directory and run `npm i spooky tiny-jsonrpc` inside. We do not need a `package.json` here, so you can forget about `--save` or `--save-dev`.

### 3. Test the given example

If SpookyJS is installed, you should have a local `node_modules` directory. Now, try to run the following command:

```
node node_modules/spooky/examples/hello.js
```

If you get "*Hello, from Spooky the Tuff Little Ghost - Wikipedia*", congrats! You can now integrate SpookyJS in your project, but you will have to respect the syntax presented in `hello.js`...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am now running into the problem that 'spooky.start' is not a function. The node function for the command you put in ran as well.

Comment: What do you get when you run `node node_modules/spooky/examples/hello.js`? If you get an error here, it means that SpookyJS is not installed properly...

Comment: I get the message "Hello, from Spooky the Tuff Little Ghost - Wikipedia". Copied and pasted from the terminal it ran from. Is possible that there is a slight difference when running on Mac?

Comment: Cool. Spooky works on your system. Now use `hello.js` as a reference for your own script... Did you read the code in this file?

Comment: Ahh I see now. Got impatient and ain't read the whole way through for sure lol. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can't include js files to phantom. you need to open a page and then you can includejs into it. page will accept js files. not phantom.

Please refer [this](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html)

> includeJs(url, callback) {void}
>
> Includes external script from the specified url (usually a remote
>   location) on the page and executes the callback upon completion.

Comment: I have looked into your solution, but I am now getting the error that the webpage module. I looked around and understand that it is a module of PhantomJS and not NodeJS, but that literally doesn't help me at all in order to figure out what's going on.

Comment: ^webpage module can not be found*